# Asycn problems with node and mongoose

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

So I am completely new to node and I am trying to complete a simple web app for a class.
Essentially I have some code that wants to add a user to the database and depending on whether the addition to the database was successful or whether the password was wrong or the username is longer than 128 char then I want to return a value. So dude in my example is acting as that value. and I wanted to return dude = 100 or whatever I set it to but dude continues to be 0. How do I go about "waiting" so that dude can  be 100 that doesn't involve a settimeout. Thanks!

```
    exports.add= function (user, password) { 
    var dude = 0;
    User.findOne({'local.user' : user, function(err, current_user) {
     dude = 100;
    });
    return dude;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty common problem for new users of asynchronous programming. What you're trying to do is return a value from a synchronous function which depends on the outcome of an asynchronous function. In this case, `return dude` is actually called before you ever set `dude = 100;`. You'll need to accept a callback to that add function which can be called once the add is complete. Something like the following:

```
exports.add = function (user, password, done) { 
  User.findOne({'local.user' : user, function(err, current_user) {
   done(err, 100); //  pass the err and code to the callback
  });
}
```

### update

Zooming out a bit, this is how you would use your new module.

```
var User = require('./user'); // load the module defined above.

User.add(user, password, function(err, code) {
  if(err || code === 123) {
    // Do something here.
  }
});
```

This defines an inline function which is called when User.add is done adding the user. Zooming out a bit more (assuming Express) would look something like:

```
var User = require('./user'); // load the module defined above.

app.post('/user/', function(req, res) {
  var user = buildUserFromReq(req);
  var password = req.body.password;

  User.add(user, password, function(err, code) {
    if(err) {
      return res.send('cannot add user', err);
    }

    res.send('user added');
  });

});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this is a great answer I just can't wrap my head around this though! so I would make calls to done with the particular value I want to return but then where is done defined? Also you say to call done once add is complete but I'm not sure where that call is being made, once again thanks so much!

Comment: I've added some examples to the answer which show you how you'd use the add function with a callback.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much!!  A lot of people say 'oh just use callbacks' but I didn't know what they were and even reading about them just made me more confused but this really clarifies a lot! Thanks again!